# json_encode only spits out one row of database into object

Tags: php, mysql, object, json

So, I am trying to get all my rows out of my database, and then be able to list and manipulate them within javascript. So far, all my research as pointed me towards objects.

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['username']) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM potentials";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $potential = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array[] = $row;
    }
    $myJSON = json_encode($array);
    echo $myJSON;
?>
```

And my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var potentialModels = <?php print($myJSON); ?>;
        console.log(potentialModels);
    });
</script>
```

I get this returned in the console:

```
[Object]
    0: Object
    length: 1
   __proto__: Array[0]
```

but shouldnt it be:

```
Object {Models: Array[2]}
    Models: Array[2]
        0: Object
            address: "407 Forby Estates Dr "
            age: ""
            city: "Eureka"
            dayofweek: ""
            email: "rebekahkeller@yahoo.com"
            firstname: "Maddie"
            id: "54"
            joindate: "2013-04-09 16:25:38"
            lastname: "Keller"
            parentname: "Rick Bross"
            parentnumber: "0"
            phone: "6367511428"
            state: "MO"
            timeofday: "after 9:30 am"
            twitter: ""
            zip: "63025"
            __proto__: Object
        1: Object
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

Should I be using aforeach instead of a while loop in my PHP statement?

Once I have all the rows in objects (or an array of objects? idk!?!?), how do I retrieve the values?

Comment: You're json_encoding twice?

Comment: code updated, still same result:

Comment: Should I be using a foreach or something? the length of the object ='s 1 and not the number of rows in my DB.

Comment: What's inside `$myJSON`? Does it contain the correct JSON string? If it's an array why `console.log()` shows it's an object?

Comment: Yeah it does, when I echo it I see a good string, but with only one row in it.

Comment: [{"id":"67","firstname":"Rick","lastname":"Bross","age":"19","email":"rbross3@gmail.com","phone":"8164896991","timeofday":"After 5:30PM","dayofweek":"Fridays","address":"1234 Cooper","city":"Raymore","state":"MO","zip":"64130","joindate":"2013-04-14 08:37:16","twitter":"@rick_bross","parentname":"","parentnumber":""}]

Comment: Is there only one row in the database? If not, could I see a json dump of a few more rows, to make sure the encoding is working as intended?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out, its now getting all the rows. How do I get the all of the firstname's from the objects?

Comment: structure updated above. Add it as a reply and I will accept your answer.